# Using Django, how can I detect an admin in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have functions in my JavaScript which I would not like to be available to normal users, and only to admins/staff. Ideally I can create a boolean variable which is true/false depending on whether the request user is staff or not, but how would I set this boolean?

Note: I'm not trying to disable them for security, but only for user experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try use [yesno](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno) filter inside js, for example:

```
var is_staff = {{ request.user.is_staff|yesno:"true,false" }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can be viewed and very easily manipulated through a browser (hit F12 on most browsers and you can debug and change flags with ease).

I would suggest that you check the user server side before displaying your page and put the relevant Javascript functions on the page only if they have the correct access. You could do this by having two different views. I would then also ensure that any calls made to the server are then checked server side for the appropriate access rights.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of passing Django variables to JavaScript is by declaring a global function in your JS file and calling it in the template file.

For Example:

index.html

```
{% block javascript %}
  <script>
   var isStaff = {{user.is_staff}};
   // Global function which calls your required function if user is a staff
   isUserStaff(isUserStaff);
  </script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```